# Class ID in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The [case class Rating](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L504) is a part of `ALS.scala`
I can not find the source code for `ID` class (or object). Can somebody share the link for this class? It should be open source. How I understand, the class `ID` is not a part of `ALS.scala`, anyway I can not find import statement for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because that implementation of ALS supports **generic** `ID` types, specialized for Int and Long. So `ID` isn't a case class. This is what the following line means :

```
case class Rating[@specialized(Int, Long) ID](user: ID, item: ID, rating: Float)
```

**Explanation :**

> Generics in Java and the JVM, and consequently also in Scala, are implemented by using type erasure. That means that if you have an instance of a generic class, for example `List[String]`, then the compiler will throw away the information about the type argument, so that at runtime it will look like `List[Object]`.
>
> In Java, primitive types are treated very differently from reference types. One of the things that you cannot do in Java is use primitive types to fill in type parameters – for example, you cannot make a `List<int>`. If you want to create a list that holds integers, you’ll have to use the wrapper class Integer. A drawback of this approach is that you need to box each of your primitive ints into an Integer object that takes up a lot more memory. I’ve done some tests and found that on my JVM a double only takes up 8 bytes, but a Double object takes up 24 bytes. Also, the boxing and unboxing takes up processor time, which can become a serious bottleneck if you’re dealing with large collections of numbers.
>
> In Scala, the distinction between primitive types and reference types is far less great than in Java, and you can use types like Int directly for type arguments. But a `List[Int]` is still converted to a `List[Object]` at runtime because of type erasure and since primitive types are not subclasses of Object on the JVM, Scala will still box the Ints to objects of some wrapper class – which makes a `List[Int]` in Scala just as inefficient as a `List<Integer>` in Java.
>
> ***The `@specialized` annotation and compiler support are meant to get rid of this inefficiency.***

More on Specializing for primitive types [here](http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/).

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I undestand correct the type for user or item could be fix first by the object definition and can be different (for example long or int). Is it right?

Comment: It can be a Long or an Int yes